# Is there an adjective for 'speechless-making'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wanted to write about intense fear, something like *abject terror*, but implying that it strikes you dumb with fear. Am I missing something obvious, or should I just settle for changing the wording to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 10):

There is exactly such a word:

> **dumbstruck**
>   *adjective*
>   so shocked or surprised as to be unable to speak: *he was dumbstruck with terror*.

[NOAD]

Comment: *Dumbfounded* would also work; which is better depends on context.

Comment: I think OP is looking for an adjective describing the object that makes you dumbstruck. That is, *horrifying* is to *horrified* as *x* is to *dumbstruck*.

Comment: @Tim: To be *dumbfounded* is to be confused or perplexed; it means you have encountered an extremely puzzling situation, not necessarily a terrifying one.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for stupefying?

Comment: Hmm, I admit that I hadn't thought of that. At first glance it doesn't seem like what I was looking for, but I may come round to it. 'Stupefying terror' feels slightly tautological.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of *stunning, paralysing, shocking, staggering, traumatising, devastating, demolishing, overwhelming, shattering, ravaging* terror.

Comment: That's one heck of a terror!

Comment: @Hellion: he, he, yes.

Comment: I like stunning, and paralysing is quite good (I did also have 'deer in the headlights' in mind as a metaphor).

Answer (score 1):

Another option I thought of today was *aphonic*, but I think that is a tad too esoteric, and more likely just to trip readers up.

In the end, I think the solution was staring me in the face:

> abject, speechless terror

Answer (score 1):

What about "I was rendered speechless"?  It might be so common that it's more of a cliche.

Answer (score 0):

“nonplus” answers the broad question posed by your title.